# Numba: UntypedAttributeError in class method

Tags: numba

I have the following class and method that should convolve an array with a kernel.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft2 as FFT, ifft2 as IFFT
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import trange, tqdm
from numba import jit

from time import sleep

import _kernel

class convolve(object):
    """ contains methods to convolve two images """
    def __init__(self, image_array, kernel):
        self.array = image_array
        self.kernel = kernel

        self.__rangeX_ = self.array.shape[0]
        self.__rangeY_ = self.array.shape[1]

        self.__rangeKX_ = self.kernel.shape[0]
        self.__rangeKY_ = self.kernel.shape[1]

        if (self.__rangeKX_ >= self.__rangeX_ or \
            self.__rangeKY_ >= self.__rangeY_):
            raise ValueError('Must submit suitable sizes for convolution.')

    @jit(nopython=True)
    def spaceConv(self):
        """ normal convolution, O(N^2*n^2). This is usually too slow """

        # pad array for convolution
        offsetX = self.__rangeKX_ // 2
        offsetY = self.__rangeKY_ // 2

        self.array = np.pad(self.array,               \
            [(offsetY, offsetY), (offsetX, offsetX)], \
               mode='constant', constant_values=0)

        # this is the O(N^2) part of this algorithm
        for i in xrange(self.__rangeX_ - 2*offsetX):
            for j in xrange(self.__rangeY_ - 2*offsetY):
                # Now O(n^2) portion
                total = 0.0
                for k in xrange(2*offsetX+1):
                    for t in xrange(2*offsetY+1):
                        total += self.kernel[k][t] * self.array[i+k][j+t]
                self.array[i+offsetX][j+offsetY] = total

        return self.array
```

As an additional note (in case anyone asks), _kernel just generates specific kernels one may want to convolve the image with (e.g. Gaussian, Moffat, etc.), so it has nothing to do with this class.

When I call the above class on an image and kernel, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fftconv.py", line 147, in <module>
    plt.imshow(conv.spaceConv(), interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 304, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
numba.errors.UntypedAttributeError: Caused By:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 249, in run
    stage()
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 465, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 789, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 717, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
UntypedAttributeError: Unknown attribute "rangeKX" of type pyobject
File "fftconv.py", line 45
[1] During: typing of get attribute at fftconv.py (45)

Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute "rangeKX" of type pyobject
File "fftconv.py", line 45
[1] During: typing of get attribute at fftconv.py (45)

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: cannot determine Numba type of value <__main__.convolve object at 0xaff5628c>
```

Usually I'm pretty good at tracing through Python errors to the cause, but because I'm not familiar with the inner-works of Numba, I'm not sure why it doesn't know what type `offsetX` is. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One step performed by numba is type-inference. This assigns types to the different values present in the function so that it can compile (in a way that it works fast).

The error means that numba doesn't understand the first input argument on the function (self in this case). Numba works best in plain functions where the arguments are scalars or array (all numeric). One option would be to move the O(n^2) loop into a function of its own and have that function receive the arrays and any other value explicitly, and decorate that function with numba.njit (or numba.jit(nopython=True), which are equivalent

Also worth a try is just trying the code "as is" removing the "nopython=True". If the performance is good enough then leave it alone :). That may happen, as numba.jit is able to detect loops inside the code that can be compiled in "no python" mode and automatically do what is needed so that the loop itself is compiled in full speed mode. The explicit "nopython=True" keyword disables that mode though.